# How to add a new record in django admin list_view, in a way similar to what extra forms do in inlines

Tags: django, django-admin

Using [ModelAdmin.list_editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) I can edit the fields of records listed in a list view of django admin, in a way similar to what is done with InlineModelAdmin.

Using [InlineModelAdmin.extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra) I can show forms to add new records in inline models admin view.

How can I show similar empty forms in the admin list view in order to add new records?